# C# socket.Send get error as soon as possible

Tags: c#, sockets

Let's review a small socket app. In this app I've read some data from another host and send some data back.

If I broke connection between hosts (disconnect ethernet cable for example), I've don't get error on first Send call (it's finished with success). Error will apear later (after 50 seconds). How do I can decrease this time? There is no option to implement "protocol" for data exchange (I can't change remote side, so I can't force it to send me acknowledgment on data actually recieved).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SocketTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
                {
                    SendTimeout = 500,
                    ReceiveTimeout = 500
                };
                socket.Connect("192.168.101.253", 4001);
                socket.NoDelay = true;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (socket.Available > 0)
                    {
                        var answer = new byte[128];
                        var actualRead = socket.Receive(answer);
                        answer = answer.Take(actualRead).ToArray();
                        Console.WriteLine("Recieved:{0}", BitConverter.ToString(answer));
                        var strCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(answer);
                        Console.WriteLine("Recieved:{0}", strCommand);
                    }

                    socket.Send(new byte[10] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0});

                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would take out the socket.Available test and block on the receive

Comment: I can't block on Receive. If no data in socket I must send something to another side.